# Set an HTML Input value by draggable SVG shape ? (or canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to put together a GUI for setting some pricing.
There are three categories to be represented graphically, and two sliders with which we want for setting suggested Buy/Sell prices.

As an exercise, I scratched together some prototypes and put them [**here on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69egn/2/).
please take a quick look, it will explain it MUCH more effectively than my words *ever* could :) 
(Please forgive my JS ... haven't refactored it yet)

Since our goal is to have the sliders set a float in an HTML input, I'm leaning toward the SVG.

1. My first request is simply a peer-review of my choice to persue an SVG solution ... just want to make sure there isn't some inherent and painful hitch that I'm bound to encounter. I'm open to arguments for other solutions too.
2. Second is a question.  Does anyone have any good links/examples to post that can help me understand how to set an input value based on the position of a shape?

(I'm expecting that the position will represent a percentage of a defined $$ range, and therefore we can extrapolate a specific $$ value)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I strongly concur with your choice of SVG over Canvas; the use of an _immediate mode_ drawing system like canvas is just asking for extra work when you need per-object event handling and simple updates.

Comment: Oh, and to be sure: you _do_ know about [HTML5 range inputs](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php), right?

Comment: @Phrogz , ya thanks ... I was originally hoping to use range inputs, but the non-support by FF killed that dream :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo I made that uses SVG to set four inputs, and vice-versa:
http://phrogz.net/svg/complex-plane-picker.xhtml

The top two inputs are the X and Y (real and complex components); the bottom two are polar coordinates (magnitude and angle).

There's likely more code in there than you need (auto-scaling as you get near the edge/middle, drawing updated axis ticks), which may make it more confusing as a demo than helpful.

In general, though, you need to:

- Have an event listener on the `keyup` or `change` or `input` events of the inputs, and update the SVG to match accordingly.
- Add dragging to your SVG element, and during dragging calculate the appropriate value(s) and set the `.value` for the input(s) accordingly.

As a tip, during dragging don't attempt to detect `mousemove` on your draggable element itself. If the mouse moves outside this, you'll stop getting drag events and it won't keep up. Instead, I generally use this logic:

- On `mousedown`:

  1. Record the current cursor position
  2. Register a `mousemove` handler **on the root of the document**
  3. Register a `mouseup` handler **on the root of the document**
- On `mousemove`:

  1. Detect the screenspace delta between the current cursor position and the position at drag start, and use this to [calculate the delta in the local space of the element being dragged](http://phrogz.net/svg/drag_under_transformation.xhtml) to update its transformation.
- On `mouseup`:

  1. Unregister the `mousemove` handler.

Here's the full source code, in the unlikely event that my site is down:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>SVG Complex Plane Input</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body { background:#eee; margin:0 }
    p { margin:0.5em; text-align:center }
    .complex-plane-picker svg { width:200px; height:200px; display:block; margin:1em auto; stroke-linejoin:round; stroke-linecap:round; pointer-events:all; }
    .complex-plane-picker rect.bg { fill:#fff; }
    .complex-plane-picker .axes * { stroke:#ccc; fill:none }
    .complex-plane-picker .dot { fill:#090; fill-opacity:0.4; stroke:#000; stroke-opacity:0.6; cursor:move; }
    .complex-plane-picker input { width:6em; }
    .complex-plane-picker .labels { stroke:none; font-size:6px; font-family:'Verdana'; text-anchor:middle; alignment-baseline:middle; }
    .complex-plane-picker .scalers { pointer-events:all; }
  </style>
</head><body>
<p>Drag the dot to set the complex value.<br/> TODO: Hold down shift to affect only the magnitude. Hold down alt to affect only the angle. Hold down both to snap to the nearest real- or imaginary-only value.</p>
<div class="complex-plane-picker">
  <p class="rectangular"><input type="number" value="0" class='real' />+<input type="number" value="0" class='imaginary' />i</p>
  <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
    <rect class="bg" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100" />
    <g class="scalers">
      <rect x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="#ffc"/>
      <rect x="-45" y="-45" width="90" height="90" fill="none" stroke="#ffc" stroke-width="10" />
    </g>
    <g class="axes">
      <g>
        <line x1="-49" y1="0" x2="49" y2="0" />
        <polyline points="-44,5 -49,0 -44,-5" />
        <polyline points="44,5 49,0 44,-5" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(90)">
        <line x1="-49" y1="0" x2="49" y2="0" />
        <polyline points="-44,5 -49,0 -44,-5" />
        <polyline points="44,5 49,0 44,-5" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="labels" id="labels">
      <text x="0" y="0">0</text>
      <text x="0" y="0">0</text>
      <text x="0" y="0">0</text>
      <text x="0" y="0">0</text>
    </g>
    <use class="labels" xlink:href="#labels" transform="rotate(90)" />
    <circle class="dot" r="4" />
  </svg>
  <p class="polar"><input type="number" value="0" class='magnitude' />@<input type="number" value="0" class='angle'/>°</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  var svg   = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
  var pt    = svg.createSVGPoint();

  function mxy(evt){
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  }

  var dot  = document.querySelector('.complex-plane-picker .dot');
  var real = document.querySelector('.real');
  var imag = document.querySelector('.imaginary');
  var size = document.querySelector('.magnitude');
  var angl = document.querySelector('.angle');

  var labels = svg.querySelectorAll('.complex-plane-picker #labels text');
  var scale, maxValue;
  var updateScale = function(newScale){
    scale = newScale;
    maxValue = 50*scale;
    var tickSize=1e-6;
    var e=-5;
    var f=-1;
    var fs = [1,2,5]
    while (tickSize/scale < 10){
      if (++f%fs.length==0) ++e;
      tickSize = fs[f%fs.length]*Math.pow(10,e);
    }
    for (var i=labels.length;i;--i){
      labels[i-1].firstChild.nodeValue = (tickSize*i).toString().replace(/(\.0*[^0]+)0{3,}.*/,'$1');
      labels[i-1].setAttribute('y', -tickSize*i/scale);
    }
    // updateRectangularFromDot();
    // updatePolarFromDot();
  };

  var rescaleAsNeeded = function(x,y,jump){
    var scaleFactor = 1.03;
    if (jump && (x>maxValue || y>maxValue || (x<maxValue*0.1 && y<maxValue*0.1))){
      updateScale(Math.max(x,y)*2/50);
    } else if (x>maxValue*0.8 || y>maxValue*0.8) updateScale(scale*scaleFactor);
    else if (x<maxValue*0.1 && y<maxValue*0.1) updateScale(scale/scaleFactor);
  };  

  var updateFromRectangular = function(){
    var x = real.value*1;
    var y = imag.value*1;
    rescaleAsNeeded(x,y,true);
    dot.cx.baseVal.value =  x/scale;
    dot.cy.baseVal.value = -y/scale;
    updatePolarFromDot();
  };
  real.addEventListener('input',updateFromRectangular,false);
  imag.addEventListener('input',updateFromRectangular,false);

  var updateFromPolar = function(){
    var hyp = size.value*1;
    var rad = angl.value*Math.PI/180;
    var x   = Math.cos(rad)*hyp;
    var y   = Math.sin(rad)*hyp;
    rescaleAsNeeded(x,y,true);
    dot.cx.baseVal.value =  x/scale;
    dot.cy.baseVal.value = -y/scale;
    updateRectangularFromDot();
  };
  size.addEventListener('input',updateFromPolar,false);
  angl.addEventListener('input',updateFromPolar,false);

  var updateRectangularFromDot = function(){
    real.value = ( dot.cx.baseVal.value*scale).toFixed(2);
    imag.value = (-dot.cy.baseVal.value*scale).toFixed(2);
  };
  var updatePolarFromDot = function(){
    var x =  dot.cx.baseVal.value*scale;
    var y = -dot.cy.baseVal.value*scale;
    size.value = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y).toFixed(2);
    angl.value = (Math.atan2(y,x)*180/Math.PI).toFixed(1);
  }
  var dragging = false;
  dot.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
    var offset = mxy(evt);
    dragging = true;
    offset.x = dot.cx.baseVal.value - offset.x;
    offset.y = dot.cy.baseVal.value - offset.y;
    var scaleTimer;
    var move = function(evt){
      clearTimeout(scaleTimer);
      var now = mxy(evt);
      var x = offset.x + now.x;
      var y = -(offset.y + now.y);
      dot.cx.baseVal.value = x;
      dot.cy.baseVal.value = -y;
      x = Math.abs(x)*scale, y=Math.abs(y)*scale;
      var oldScale = scale;
      rescaleAsNeeded(x,y);
      updatePolarFromDot();
      updateRectangularFromDot();
      if (oldScale != scale) scaleTimer = setTimeout(function(){move(evt)},1000/30);
    };
    document.documentElement.style.userSelect = 
    document.documentElement.style.MozUserSelect = 
    document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
    svg.addEventListener('mousemove',move,false);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
      dragging = false;
      clearTimeout(scaleTimer);
      svg.removeEventListener('mousemove',move,false);
      document.documentElement.style.userSelect = 
      document.documentElement.style.MozUserSelect = 
      document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect = '';
    },false);
  },false);

  dot.addEventListener('dblclick',function(){
    dot.cx.baseVal.value = dot.cy.baseVal.value = 0;
    updateScale(1.0);
    updatePolarFromDot();
    updateRectangularFromDot();
  },false);

  updateScale(1.0);

]]></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Fyi, the SHIFT and ALT modifiers on your site aren't working for me (Chrome & FF).

Comment: @mOrloff That's why it says "TODO" in front of it; apparently I got distracted from that project and never finished those features. ;)

Comment: it would be **really REALLY** cool if you turned that into a tutorial --or even just put copious amounts of very descriptive comments right into your JavaScript ...   JS is still a bit unnatural for me and I'm trying to tear it apart, make sense of it and keep it all straight, but I'm struggling considerably :)

Comment: @mOrloff I'll see if I can find the time to do this.

Comment: Well @Phrogz , my tinkering has gotten me quite far. I've stripped it down to [**this**](http://pastebin.com/vWVuurf2) .. My next step is getting it to play nice with TWO sliders .. if it'd be OK for me to contact you with questions, please ping me at the email in the bottom of that paste .. Regardless, thanks-a-bunch :)