# Javascript error on code for Draggable SVG shape

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm working with some code provided via [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128785/set-an-html-input-value-by-draggable-svg-shape-or-canvas/11129028), courtesy of @Phrogz.
I've now tweaked and trimmed it to a launch-point for my needs, so I'm trying to plug that JS into my test page.
I threw [**a copy of my test page here**](http://pastebin.com/MM90KxK5) on Pastebin.

I'm getting this error (courtesy of line 126): 
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null***

My attempts to this point have all revolved around the guess that the *updateFromInput* function is at the heart of the error.  I played with it all the ways that I could think of, and no dice :) 
Granted, though, I'm *faaar* from being a JS master, so ...

Can someone explain why the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, input_1 is null.

<strike>The problem could be with querySelector. You could instead try getElementsByClassName.</strike>

Oh, your class on your element is "input1" but you're selecting "input_1". Easy mistake :)